# Create a dynamic "cross section" for competence vs. confidence chart in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

I have created a confidence vs. competence chart using Report Builder 3.0. Currently the "cross section" of the chart is static and separated by a background image on the chart.

Like this:

[image]

However, as a requirement, the cross section needs to be dynamic. I can remove the background image (it isn't needed). I can pass the values for the both the x and y axis into the report when the lines need to cross. The problem is trying to actually implement this on the chart.

[image]

Can anyone provide a solution or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross section is just a line graph (or two) overlayed on your original chart.

Here's an example of overlayed charts:

http://www.sqljason.com/2012/03/overlapping-charts-in-ssrs-using-range.html